# GitHub updating repository?

Tags: linux, centos, git

I am trying to setup GitHub on my server and gotten to the point where I am running the command "git push -u origin master". However, a large file was detected and the following error was received:

```
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected.
remote: error: Trace: 5520a70fd2eeaa2eafd7de049a590fb5
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File app/logs/dev.log is 2041.59 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100 MB
```

I ended up deleting that file and tried adding the git again but I keep running into that error. Any ideas on how to work around this?

Comment: It would be kind of you to go back to your old questions and mark answers as "accepted".

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the page they linked you to?

You are trying to push ridiculously large log files into that Github repo. Don't do that! Add `*.log` or `app/logs/*` to your `.gitignore` file and you wont' have to deal with this again.